# Sum of all $3-$ digit even palindrome

Tags: permutations, combinations, palindrome

Find the sum of all $3-$digit even palindromes.

Now number of even $3-$digit palindromes will be $10 \times 4=40$ but how to proceed to find sum?

Could someone give me some hint to proceed?

Comment: How many of those palindromes end in a $1$?  In a $2$?  In a $4$?...  How many of those palindromes have $0$ as the middle digit?  a $1$?  a $2$?... add based on digit location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a number must end in $2$, $4$, $6$ or $8$ and begin with the same digit. It is not too difficult to add them up by using the formula for a finite arithmetic series.
$$
(202+212+\dotsb+292)+(404+414+\dotsb+494)+\dotsb (808+818+\dotsb+898) \tag{1}
$$
For example the term in the first bracket can be computed as
$$
\frac{10(202+292)}{2}.
$$
The general formula for a finite arithmetic series with $n$ terms, first term $a$ and last term $b$ is 
$$
\frac{n(a+b)}{2}.
$$
You can compute the rest of (1) in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

Each three digit even palindome will have the form $aba$ where $a=2,4,6,8$ and $b=0,1,\cdots,9$. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
S=\sum_{a=2,4,6,8} \sum_{b=0}^{9} (101a+10b)=  \color{red}{2470}.
\end{eqnarray*}